# How do I set up the recyclerView adapter?

Tags: android, json, asynchronous, android-asynctask

So, I don't know how should I do it. I want to get jsonData and set up an adapter with this data from the same Activtiy. Is this even possible? If yes how should I do it, because it always crashes out for me because of the delay of the "download". The adapter wants to set up earlier than I get the data so it will crash out because of the null length array.

```
private SzabadEuMusorok[] mSzabadEuMusoroks;

@InjectView(R.id.archivumReyclerView)
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_archivum);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);

    setArray();

    CollectionsAdapter adapter = new CollectionsAdapter(this, mSzabadEuMusoroks);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
}
```

Comment: Set setAdapter() inside your downloader ......

Comment: Where should I set it? What downloader?

Comment: where is your JSON data ??

Comment: I get it in the setArray() method, after that I parse it and give it into the mSzabadEuMusoroks variable

Comment: Set `setAdapter()` inside  where you get exact all data in `setArray()` method ....

Answer (score 0):

**Please make sure to set the adapter only after you get data from calling webservice**

please got follow below so that you get an overview on how to implement it:

```
      public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
            private SzabadEuMusorok[] mSzabadEuMusoroks;

            @InjectView(R.id.archivumReyclerView)
            RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager ;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_archivum);
                ButterKnife.inject(this);

                setArray();


                layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

      new LongOperation().execute("");//call your webservice
            }



                private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                            try {

            //call your webservice here
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                Thread.interrupted();
                            }
                        }
                        return serviceResult;// this will be passed to onPostExecute
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

                mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                   CollectionsAdapter adapter = new CollectionsAdapter(this, mSzabadEuMusoroks);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);   //set your adapter using result in webservice called in doinbackground
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
            // show a progress dialog 

            }

                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I want to do it with OkHttp. After I set it all up I'm calling setAdapter and now it crashes with exception: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: call inside your okhttp response `setAdapter()` after response success ....

Comment: Please copy all the code in onPostExecute(String result) to your responseSuccess block